# Sum Country Total

Tags: r, group-by, sum

I've been having an issue that seems relatively simple, but I haven't been able to do it correctly. I saw that it was done with just grouping by one column, but I'm not sure how to tackle this since I'm trying to append months that are different values.

```
Country Year Month Total
Brazil  2007   1     20
Brazil  2007   2     20
Brazil  2007   3     20
Canada  2007   1     10
... 
Brazil  2008   10   10


I'm trying to add the monthly total(1-12) for each country per each year(ex:2007-2010 so rather than the month tab I just have the yearly total for one country.
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `dplyr` for this,

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
    group_by(country, year) %>%
    summarise(
          total = sum(Total)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `base R` (no packages needed)

```
aggregate(Total ~ ., df1[c('Country', 'Year', 'Total')], sum)
```

Comment: Base R are always my favorite solutions. Base R plus the formula interface should be upvoted twice.

Comment: `dplyr` for the win!